# How are transaction fees split in the network?

Tags: transaction-fees, mining-pools, mining-reward

1. How are transaction fees split in the network, do all the transaction fees go directly to the miner or is there any kind of percentage of fee allocation to peers/validators for relaying transactions and validating?
2. If yes, how and on what basis does they share the transaction fees among themselves?

Answer (score 4):

All transaction fees go to the miner that published the block in which the transaction got confirmed. If the miner is a mining pool, they tend to have some distribution mechanism to pay out to the pool contributors.

Full nodes do not get paid. Users run full nodes because they want to have their own trusted source on the state of the network.